# $\|f\|_1=0$ if and only if $f=0$ almost everywhere

Tags: lebesgue-integral

I feel like it's a well established fact that if the $L^1$ norm of an integrable function is zero then, it must be zero almost everywhere, but what's the proof?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the measurable sets $E_n = \{x: |f(x)| \ge 1/n \}$.  Then 
$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n = \{x: f(x) \ne 0\}$.  If it's not the case that $f= 0$ almost everywhere, this has nonzero measure, so by countable additivity some $E_n$ has nonzero measure.  If $m(E_n) > 0$, 
then $\|f \| \ge \int_{E_n} |f| \ge m(E_n)/n > 0$.